# C# DataGridView плохо прорисовывается до клика на него

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал форму поставил на нее DataGridView добавил строку в OnLoad формы, запускаю проект [image: введите сюда описание изображения] как только кликну на DataGridView или закрою и открою вновь форму все норм [image: введите сюда описание изображения] вот код главной формы

```html
private void managment_menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      using(var form = new Form1()) {
        form.ShowDialog();
      }
    }
```

Вот собственно код формы с DataGridView

```html
public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "Test";
    }
  }
```

:D создал новый проект сделал и всё работает, что это может быть?

DataGridView создаю просто через Toolbox тащу на форму

Comment: _просто ... тащу на форму_ - нет, не просто тащите. Судя по наличию колонок в гриде, вы их тем или иным образом создаёте. Но упорно не приводите всей информации.

Comment: Обращение к `Rows[0]` требует, чтобы эта строка с индексом 0 была в гриде. Если её нет - будет исключение. У вас обрабатываются exception? Причин может быть много, не видя весь код, сложно дать ответ.

Comment: Ошибка не в коде, решил проблему, ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

Предоставьте код. Обработчика OnLoad формы и OnClick, после которого у вас загружается все. И код обработчика Activated.

Вот я заполнил таблицу в OnLoad.

[image: Заполнил таблицу в обработчике OnLoad.]

**Код:**

```
        private void Form1_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "1111";
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "2222";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, я понял. Если у вас происходит загрузка только в Activated событии вашего DataGridView, то вы, наверное, не знаете, что Activated происходит при клике на контрол. Вроде бы не только при нем, но при клике тоже.

Comment: Activated происходит при активации формы, не только при клике, но мне надо загружать данные из БД только 1 раз в datagridview форму, при activated надо чистить таблицу каждый раз, и загрузка каждый раз будет...

Comment: Странно, что не получается в OnLoad. Попробуйте загрузить не из базы данных, а вручную, как я написал во втором ответе. Получается?

Comment: @MikeWaters Кроме того, если я не ошибаюсь, то если по умолчанию у вас в таблице одна строка, то загрузить вы можете данные только в эту строку. Далее нужно добавлять строки(AddRow(), как-то так), и заполнять их. Возможно, у вас при первой попытке загрузки сначала идет попытка заполнить данными несуществующую строку, а затем добавление строки? Проверьте.

Comment: Вручную тоже так

Comment: ?? Интересно. Скиньте, как вы заполняете вручную. Проверю у себя, это уже интересно. Скиньте код, без него сложно будет вам помочь.